# import qgis geoprocessing tools in python os x 10.9.5

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, mac, sip

I'd like to use the python bindings from qgis, but in a standalone project.
I need the geoprocessing tools for vectors.

I updated QGIS (Wien - 2.8), python (3.4.3), etc.
However, it always ends with the following error :

> > > import qgis.core
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis/**init**.py", line 26, in 
> > >           import sip
> > >       ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/sip.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
> > >         Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/sip.so
> > >         Expected in: flat namespace
> > >        in /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/sip.so

I set the following path :
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/:/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Frameworks/

The issue is obviously about SIP, but I truly don't know what to do.
The python console inside QGIS is not insulting me when I'm giving it "import qgis.core".
So I 'd bet there is something about the versions of SIP, Python "command line" and Python "QGIS command line".

I can't say what... and I'mm really stuck.

I am using miniconda3 for my libraries (rsgislib, gdal, ogr, ...).

Comment: Is QGIS built with Python3? If you are using two different versions of Python that will be causing problems. Not sure if that will cause this specific error but it will cause some errors.